# Linux implementation of TS gateway

Tags: linux, windows, remote-desktop, gateway

I was wondering if there is a linux implementation of a TS Gateway, like the one present in Windows Server 2008.

My scenario, I have a Windows remote desktop client behind a Linux Gateway at home, which I would like to access while at work. I understand that I could simply forward the necessary port, but that would simply introduce more complications if others in my house wanted a similar functionality.

Comment: From my experience with TS Gateway and RD on Linux, this would be hard to implement.  If you find something, please be sure to update, as I would be interested.  Also, please be careful on how you phrase your question.  As I understand it, some of the senior people here are sticklers for the "Anything in a home setting" restriction.  It may be beneficial to check out the faq.

Comment: The joys of closed protocols - I don't of anything for Linux which supports this, nor would I expect that there's anything available. But with a small number of servers, why not just use different (external) ports for different machines - as Microsoft explain here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/allow-remote-desktop-connections-from-outside-your-home-network

Comment: You could always go with VNC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ssh to the Linux server and forward the RDP port of the internal Windows machine to the computer you're using.

If you are using a computer running Linux as the remote client just use ssh in the form:

```
ssh gateway.domain.com -L 8888:rdpserver:3389
```

And then use any RDP client in Linux to connect to localhost:8888 your traffic will be forwarded to the Windows box.

If using a Windows computer as the remote client, use Bitwise's Tunnelier, this is an excellent program for this purpose, it is essentially a SSH & SFTP client for windows that has this functionality built-in